# Create a list, in which there are buttons the users click-and-hover an element, to open another

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list, looking like this:

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="hold">Click and hold this button for 500ms</div>
    <div class="show">And this element should appear.</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hold">Click and hold this button for 500ms</div>
    <div class="show">And this element should appear.</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I simply want the users to click-and-hold on the .hold div, and when 500ms has passed, the .show div appears.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can find tons of solutions on Google for this but I will explain a simple one using **jQuery**.

You have two elements represented by their respective classes. A click holder element `.hold` and a element `.show` to be shown.

Because the `.hold` elements are the responsible to trigger the function to show the hidden elements we have add two event listeners one for detect when the mouse was click and another to detect the release of the mouse.

We define a `mousedown` event to be triggered at `.hold` element when a pointing device button is pressed while the pointer is inside the element. At this point we will initiate a `timer` for 500 ms. If the `timer` is not cleared out then it will call the `showElements()` method to show the hidden elements.

Now, to know when the mouse has released the element we are going to combine two events: `mouseup` event that is the opposite to `mousedown` event and the `mouseleave` event, which is fired at the `.hold` element when the cursor of a pointing device is moved out of it. This event will clear out the `timer` setup by the `mousedown` event.

#### Update show using `slideToggle()`

Just replace the `hidden.show();` with `hidden.slideToggle('slow');`

Here is the implementation.

```js
let timer;

function showElements(holder) {
  let hidden = $(holder).closest('li').find('.show');
  hidden.slideToggle('slow');
}

$(function() {
  console.log("ready!");
  $(".show").hide(0);
});

$('.hold')
  .on('mousedown', function() {
    let holder = this;
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
      showElements(holder);
    }, 500);
  })
  .on('mouseup mouseleave', function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="hold">Click and hold this button for 500ms</div>
    <div class="show">And this element should appear.</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hold">Click and hold this button for 500ms</div>
    <div class="show">And this element should appear.</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I'm looking for a way to make this work on mobile devices, it works on my desktop, but when I go to toggle device toolbar in Chrome, it doesn't work anymore.

Also, is there a way to slideToggle the .show? :)

Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: what do mean with toggle device toolbar? this code works perfectly in a webview as well as many browsers.

Comment: It worked nicely, I'm sorry about bringing that up. But about that slideToggle, can you show me a way to do that?

Comment: Just replace the `show()` method with a `slideToggle( )`method like this. I will update

Comment: I'm with you, it's very strange. I was even kind of scared to ask this question here, since this website has a tendency to crush your soul if you don't exactly what you're talking about :(

Answer (score -1):

This is my solution: https://jsfiddle.net/xwg4jey9/11/

```js
  $(".show").hide(0);

  var timeoutId = 0;

  var showHiddens = function(hold) {
    var show = $(hold).closest("li").find(".show");
    show.show();
  }

  $('.hold').on('mousedown', function() {
    var hold = this;
    timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
      showHiddens(hold);
    }, 500);
  }).on('mouseup mouseleave', function() {
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
  });
```